# MySql case statement error

Tags: mysql

When I use this code in a create view construct it returns empty result set.
I have tried using a column name after the case and removing the column name in the when lines...no change... any ideas.   I have determined the issue is at the case statement by commenting it out and running it and it works fine then....

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW orderMSTRview
AS
SELECT SB.name "Brand", O.orderID "Order ID", O.orderRecID "Record ID", O.orderDate "Date Created", 
O.salesRepName "Sales Rep Name", O.salesRepEmail "Sales Rep Email", 
O.orderNumer "Order Number", O.orderType "Order Type",
CASE 
    when fulfillStatus = 0 then 'open'
    when fulfillStatus = 1 then 'processing'
    when fulfillStatus = 2 then 'complete'
    when fulfillStatus = 5 then 'Shipped'
    when fulfillStatus = 9 then 'void'
END as "Order Status" ,
IF(O.payStatus=0,'unpaid','paid') "Payment Status", 
O.totalOrderQuantity "Total Order Quantity",
O.subtotalOrderValue "Subtotal Order Value", 
O.totalOrderValue "Total Order Value", O.credit "Order Credit", 
O.taxAmount "Tax Amount", O.shippingCost "Shipping Cost",
O.finalInvoiceValue "Invoice Amount", O.currency "Currency", 
O.shipDate "Ship Date", O.cancelAfter "Cancel Date", O.terms "Terms", 
O.buyerName "Buyer Name", O.buyerEmail "Buyer Email", O.buyerPhone "Buyer Phone", O.custCode1 "Customer Code1", O.custCode2 "Customer Code2", 
O.custERP "Customer ERP", O.customerPO "Customer PO", O.custVat "VAT number",
O.billToName "Bill To Name", O.billToStreet1 "Bill To Address1" ,
O.billToStreet2 "Bill To Address2", O.billToCity "Bill To City",
O.billToState "Bill To State", O.billToZip "Bill To Zip code", 
O.shipToName "Ship To Name", O.shipToStreet1 "Ship To Address1", 
O.shipToStreet2 "Ship To Address2",
O.shipToCity "Ship To City", O.shipToState "Ship To State", 
O.shipToZip "Ship To Zip code", 
O.tagname1 "Tag 1", O.tagname2 "Tag 2", O.tagname3 "Tag 3"
FROM orders as O left join showroom_brand as SB on O.showroomID = SB.sid 
WHERE O.orderDate >= '2015-01-01' and SB.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: its in a large schema...nothing hinky about the data...but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this example:

try to run this

```
 set @fulfillStatus = 1;
    select 
    CASE 
        when @fulfillStatus = 0 then 'open'
        when @fulfillStatus = 1 then 'processing'
        when @fulfillStatus = 2 then 'complete'
        when @fulfillStatus = 5 then 'Shipped'
        when @fulfillStatus = 9 then 'void'
    else "None"
    END as "Order Status"
```

Comment: Case logically like this:  case when _____ then ______ else _______ end thats why it return you an error coz you dont have an else near end.

Comment: I added the else clause and no change...Thanks for the response

Comment: your query dont have fulfillStatus field thats why it returns an error..